# Call C# method in .AddJavaScriptFunction(...)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, real-time

I want use Highcharts in my ASP.NET MVC project, exactly this chart:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

How can i call C# method in .AddJavaScriptFunction(...), is it possible? The problem is the 24 line in my code.

My controller:

```
 public ActionResult SplineUpdateEachSecond()
    {
        List<object> points = new List<object>(20);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = -19; i <= 0; i++)
            points.Add(new { X = now.AddSeconds(i), Y = rand.NextDouble() });
        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .SetOptions(new GlobalOptions { Global = new Global { UseUTC = true } })
            .InitChart(new Chart
            {
                DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Spline,
                MarginRight = 10,
                Events = new ChartEvents
                {
                    Load = "ChartEventsLoad"
                }
            })
            .AddJavascripFunction("ChartEventsLoad(var t = test())",
                @"// set up the updating of the chart each second
                                   var series = this.series[0];
                                   setInterval(function() {
                                      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                         y = <%:test()%>; //HERE i want call my 'test' method, which is lower in the code
                                      series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                                   }, 1000);")
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Live random data" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Type = AxisTypes.Datetime,
                TickPixelInterval = 150
            })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis
            {
                Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Value" },
                PlotLines = new[]
                {
                    new YAxisPlotLines
                    {
                        Value = 0,
                        Width = 1,
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808080")
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "TooltipFormatter" })
            .AddJavascripFunction("TooltipFormatter",
                @"return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                   Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+ 
                                   Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);")
            .SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = false })
            .SetExporting(new Exporting { Enabled = false })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Name = "Random data",
                Data = new Data(points.ToArray())
            });

        return View(chart);
    }


    public string test() //HERE is my C# function, which i want call to above
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile("http://examplelink/example.dat", @"example.dat"); //This file is constantly changing
        string exampleString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"example.dat");
        string[] words = exampleString.Split('_');
        return words[3];
    }
```

My C# method is in the same .cs file. This is standard sample project from Highcharts, i just add method test() and i tried call it in .AddJavaScriptFunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.AddJavascripFunction("ChartEventsLoad(var t = test())",
                @"// set up the updating of the chart each second
                 var series = this.series[0];
                 setInterval(function() {
                 var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                 y = " + test(); + ";series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);}, 1000);")
```